# Rails pass object through form select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my form:

```
<%= f.select :user, User.all %>
```

This generates a select with a collection of all users.

When I hit submit, it's currently passing the object as a string, looks like below:

```
[3] pry(#<PermissionFormsController>)> params[:permission_form][:user]
=> "John Doe <John.Doe@foo.com> - Bar (something)"
```

and

```
[4] pry(#<PermissionFormsController>)> params[:permission_form][:user].class
=> String
```

I'd like to get the object rather, like `current_user`

```
[5] pry(#<PermissionFormsController>)> current_user
=> Homer Simpson <homer@gmail.com> - Foo (admin)
```

Which is an object of class `User`:

```
[6] pry(#<PermissionFormsController>)> current_user.class
=> User(id: integer, status: string, ...)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass Ruby objects directly from a form to the server, only strings. Your controller is responsible for turning this data into actual models. This is normally done by passing the object `id` and calling `YourModel.find` in the controller.

So you need to change your form like this:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.all.map{|u| [u.to_s, u.id]} %>
```

And then in your controller's action:

```
user = User.find(params[:permission_form][:user_id])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's not going to work, because now `params[:permission_form][:user_id] = "John Doe <John.Doe@foo.com> - Bar (something)"` how would get the ID to pass?

Comment: It seems you defined ``to_param`` in your ``User`` model, isn't it? You can remove that if you don't need it, or use this select code instead: ``<%= f.select :user_id, User.all.map{|u| [u.to_param, u.id]} %>``

Comment: I actually don't have `to_param` in my User model.

Comment: Where is your ``"John Doe <John.Doe@foo.com> - Bar (something)"`` coming from then? A helper? ``User#to_s``?

Comment: ```def inspect
    "#{first_name} #{last_name} <#{email}> - #{company} (#{role})"
  end
  alias_method :to_s, :inspect``` possibly from there, but I'm not calling it

Comment: You are overriding ``inspect`` and ``to_s``, that's why. I'm not sure why you need to do that, but in any case I updated my code.